# I have a work gap after my degree how should I approach finding a job?

Tags: employment-gaps

I graduated from architecture in mid 2014 and didn't look for work in the field right away as I wanted a break (I was burnt out from working too much and studying during uni) I eventually saved up for a holiday that I'd been wanting to go on since I was 12 and did a small 'job' for a family member that didn't work out that well).

As I started looking for jobs in 2015, I developed a medical condition that eventually put me into a mild depression. Now 2 years since graduation, I'm fine now and I want to continue on again, however I have no work experience in the field of my degree and I'm not sure how to approach it again.

Right now I would be very happy just to just get some work experience from anywhere, however I was wondering if I should still apply for entry level jobs. Should I let them know I'll be happy to do any kind of work, paid or unpaid on my CV? Or should that be a separate conversation? How should I explain this work gap?

Comment: Did you look at the other questions on this site dealing with work gaps?

Comment: work gaps, especially right after graduation, are very common. If inquired about, the easiest way out is "I was in the middle of a family situation, which dragged out longer than I anticipated". And family situations happen. One of your parents might have gotten sick and you needed to take care of them is a very common example. I don't believe any prospect employer will hold such a gap against you, if they want to hire you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gap years after college to go travelling or whatever are incredibly common.  In your case that's not quite what has happened but the gap won't appear extremely unusual to a HR person.   You will probably be asked about it.  You can tell the truth, just in a way that looks good.

"After college,  I went travelling for a short while as a reward for successfully completing my studies.  Unfortunately following that I developed some medical issues which I wanted to have 100% behind me before I started in the world of work.  I'm totally healthy now and eager to take a new challenge in your firm".

Now, having zero experience is probably a bigger issue.  I think approaching a firm asking for a 3 month internship on minimal (or zero) pay is a good idea if you are unable to get interviews for entry level positions.

Comment: Good answer, it's common enough and won't impact on the job search